# After upgariding hibernate search 4.3 to 5.7.0 text search is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

After upgrading Hibernate search 4.3.0.Final to 5.7.0.Final and current hibernate version is 5.2.6.Final

I got following exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.AssertionFailure: An entity got loaded even though it was not part of the EntityInfo list
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.CriteriaObjectInitializer.initializeObjects(CriteriaObjectInitializer.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.QueryLoader.executeLoad(QueryLoader.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:207)
    at com.anite.bof2.component.textsearch.impl.TextSearcher.runQuery(TextSearcher.java:50)
    at com.anite.bof2.component.textsearch.impl.DefaultLuceneTextSearch.performInclusiveTextSearch_aroundBody0(DefaultLuceneTextSearch.java:72)
    at com.anite.bof2.component.textsearch.impl.DefaultLuceneTextSearch$AjcClosure1.run(DefaultLuceneTextSearch.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
    at com.anite.bof2.component.textsearch.impl.DefaultLuceneTextSearch.performInclusiveTextSearch(DefaultLuceneTextSearch.java:32)
    at com.anite.bof2.modules.actions.query.SearchTextAction.update(SearchTextAction.java:285)
    at com.anite.bof2.modules.actions.BaseBof2PenguinAction.doPerform(BaseBof2PenguinAction.java:31)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.actions.VelocityAction.doPerform(VelocityAction.java:99)
    at org.apache.turbine.util.velocity.VelocityActionEvent.perform(VelocityActionEvent.java:177)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.actions.VelocityAction.perform(VelocityAction.java:187)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.actions.VelocitySecureAction.perform(VelocitySecureAction.java:133)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.ActionLoader.exec(ActionLoader.java:148)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.pages.DefaultPage.doBuild(DefaultPage.java:215)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.Page.build(Page.java:125)
    at org.apache.turbine.modules.PageLoader.exec(PageLoader.java:151)
    at org.apache.turbine.pipeline.ExecutePageValve.executePage(ExecutePageValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.turbine.pipeline.ExecutePageValve.invoke(ExecutePageValve.java:101)
    ... 48 more
```

**Below is the code block which gives exception**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public <T> TextResults<T> performExclusionTextSearch(TextArgs<T> args)
{
    if (args != null && args.getSearchText() != null && args.getFromDate() != null && args.getToDate() != null
            && args.getFields() != null)
    {
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
        QueryBuilder qb = getQueryBuilder(fullTextSession, args.getSearchEntity());

        try
        {
            // exclusion query
            Query query = qb
                    .bool()
                    .must(qb.keyword().onFields(args.getFields()).matching(args.getSearchText()).createQuery())
                    .not()
                    .must(qb.range().onField("captureDate").from(args.getFromDate()).to(args.getToDate())
                            .createQuery()).createQuery();

            FullTextQuery textQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, args.getSearchEntity());

            // apply any filter
            if (args.getFilter() != null)
            {
                textQuery.enableFullTextFilter(args.getFilterClass()).setParameter(args.getFilterField(),
                        args.getFilter());
            }

            return runQuery(textQuery, args.getLimit());
        }
        catch (EmptyQueryException e)
        {
            // lucene standardanalyser filtered out the query word - ignore
        }
        return new TextResults<T>(false, new ArrayList<T>(0));
    }
    else
    {
        ManagementContext.logErrorEvent("Null parameters passed to text search");
        return new TextResults<T>(false, new ArrayList<T>(0));
    }
}

protected <T> TextResults<T> runQuery(FullTextQuery query, int limit)
{       
    boolean moreDataAvailable = false;

    //apply capturedate as a sorted field
    Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("captureDate", SortField.Type.LONG, true));
    query.setSort(sort);

    int resultsize = query.getResultSize();

    if(resultsize > limit)
    {
        //return marker to indicate more results available
        moreDataAvailable = true;
        query.setMaxResults(limit);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> data = query.getResultList();   

    TextResults<T> results = new TextResults<>(moreDataAvailable, data);

    return results;
}
```

> I got error when executing below line in runQuery method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<T> data = query.getResultList();
```

My database is Oracle 11g. Above code is working fine and gives valid output with Hibernate search 4.3.0.Final.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you're updating from such an ancient version that I'm amazed your application even got past startup :)

Two things you should do before even trying to analyze the Search-related failures:

- make sure you're using a recent enough version of Hibernate ORM. In this case it should be at least ORM 5.2.3, and I'd recommend the latest (5.2.10 as I'm writing this).
- [reindex your database completely](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex). Hibernate Search changed a lot since 4.3, so your older indexes are very unlikely to work with Hibernate Search 5.7.

Comment: Yes I am using latest hibernate ORM jar also<hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final </hibernate.version>  <hibernate.search.version>5.7.0.Final</hibernate.search.version>

Comment: We also created new Index and it is a fresh database with new data.

Comment: Weird. Are you doing something particular with your entity IDs? Or perhaps you are using Hibernate Envers?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst investigating a similar issue during an upgrade from 4.3.0.Final to 5.7.0.Final, have found a possible cause for the assertion exception:-

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.AssertionFailure: An entity got loaded even though it was not part of the EntityInfo list
```

The exception can be thrown when the class being used in the search criteria has incorrectly overridden its `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to compare on identity rather than by value. This causes the Hibernate code's `LinkedHashMap.put(key, value)` method to fail to find the temporary proxy object that it expects to be in the map (that it had previously placed there) because the `key` will contain different object instances that have the same value.