# hibernate search exception - An entity got loaded even though it was not part of the EntityInfo list

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Hibernate search 5.5.2
while testing centos7 we get this exception from an integration test
(except the centos7 instead of 6 we didn't change anything.)

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.AssertionFailure: An entity got loaded even though it was not part of the EntityInfo list
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.CriteriaObjectInitializer.initializeObjects(CriteriaObjectInitializer.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.QueryLoader.executeLoad(QueryLoader.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:153)
```

do you have any idea what can cause it?

Comment: It's about database schema, I guess...

Comment: It's a serious error (`AssertionFailure`) within the hibernate search library. You should go through their bugtracker to see if there are known bugs (and if not, gather more information and submit a bug report).

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi he schema wasn't changed as I wrote above.

Comment: @Kayaman in google I found only tis q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993788/after-upgariding-hibernate-search-4-3-to-5-7-0-text-search-is-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa   and it is not my case. I have no idea how to continue

Comment: I'd suggest submitting a bug report.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3180

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happened in my project:

- We used a hierarchy of classes - same table but different discriminators
- DB was re-created, but indices were left on disk
- When searching - an old entity was found in indices which had a different type (sub-class) from what was in DB (because in DB records were created from scratch in different order).

So it found one entity type in indices, and another entity type in DB and threw this error.